# How can I generate a subject in a specific pose?

Tags: image-generation, stable-diffusion, comfyui

When creating an image of a person, general common poses ("standing", "sitting") work well enough, but anything exact or uncommon can be hard to describe and tends to get ignored by the model.

Below I try "Engineer leaning against a wall with one hand, other hand on head, standing cross-legged" with Stable Diffusion 1.5:

[image: Engineer not leaning against a wall and not standing]
(image contains ComfyUI workflow graph metadata - can be downloaded and dragged into the UI)

Are there any techniques I could use to better achieve specific poses that I have in mind?

Answer (score 4):

**ControlNets** and **T2I adapters** both allow you to condition generation on some kind of image input rather than just a text prompt. I'd suggest T2I adapters where available, as they're faster and achieve similar quality.

Specifically, there's a ControlNet and a T2I adapter for pose:

- [OpenPose ControlNet (SD 1.5)](https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/ControlNet/blob/main/models/control_sd15_openpose.pth)
- [OpenPose T2I adapter (SD 1.4)](https://huggingface.co/TencentARC/T2I-Adapter/blob/main/models/t2iadapter_openpose_sd14v1.pth)

These expect a "stickman" line skeleton pose image as input. The easiest way to generate this is from running a detector on an existing image using a preprocessor:

- For ComfyUI [ControlNet preprocessor nodes](https://github.com/Fannovel16/comfy_controlnet_preprocessors) has "OpenposePreprocessor"
- For Automatic1111's web UI the [ControlNet extension](https://github.com/Mikubill/sd-webui-controlnet) comes with a preprocessor dropdown - [install instructions](https://github.com/Mikubill/sd-webui-controlnet#installation)

Both of the above also work for T2I adapters. To set them up in ComfyUI, you'd want to feed the reference image into OpenposePreprocessor to generate the pose stickman image, then feed that alongside the ControlNet/T2I adapter model and text prompt conditioning into a "Apply ControlNet" node to get the updated conditioning.

[image: ComfyUI workflow graph]

I used https://app.posemy.art/ to create the image from which to generate the pose stickman:

[image]

The pose stickman generated from it:

[image]

Final result:

[image: Engineer in the requested pose, more or less]
(image contains ComfyUI workflow graph metadata - can be downloaded and dragged into the UI)