# What prompt is required to have a subject fully in frame using Stable Diffusion based AI image generation?

Tags: prompt-design, stable-diffusion, negative-prompt

When using an AI image generation package based on Stable Diffusion (For example, [Automatic1111 Stable Diffusion web UI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui), or [Stable Diffusion Infinity](https://huggingface.co/spaces/lnyan/stablediffusion-infinity)), what prompt (+ or -) is required to have your subject centered on the image with none of its components clipped\cut off?

For example, to have a red car center frame, without the hood or boot out of frame on the left\right side. Or to have a person in a traditional portrait pose with an equal amount of space to the left and right of them, and space above the top of their head.

Answer (score 4):

The issue likely stems from the fact that Stable Diffusion 1 & 2 were trained on square crops of images:

> Synthesized objects can be cropped, such as the cut-off head of the cat in the left examples for SD 1-5 and SD 2-1. An intuitive explanation for this behavior is the use of random cropping during training of the model: As collating a batch in DL frameworks such as PyTorch [32] requires tensors of the same size, a typical processing pipeline is to (i) resize an image such that the shortest size matches the desired target size, followed by (ii) randomly cropping the image along the longer axis

(source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.01952.pdf)

Some potential solutions:

1. **Model choice**: [Stable Diffusion XL](https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0) addresses this issue by having the amount of cropping as a conditioning parameter, so that the model is aware of it and it can be set to zero during generation, and additionally fine-tuning on multiple aspect ratios. If you're able to, using SDXL (it's free and works in Automatic1111's web UI, but requires more VRAM) should fix this issue:

[image: Comparison of two generated images, showing that Stable Diffusion XL results in better framing than Stable Diffusion 1.5]

2. **Text prompt**: Using "cropped" or "uncropped" may be ineffective, because the random cropping was performed without adjusting the prompt, so the model will have seen even "uncropped" images as cropped. Words that indicate the subject is small and in the centre of the image, and so less likely to have been cropped out by the random cropping, may show better results - but it's still a bit hit and miss:

[image: Comparison of two generated images, showing that adding "small, surrounded by empty space" to the prompt results in head no longer being cropped out]

3. **Image-to-image, ControlNets, and T2I adapters**: There are many ways you can use a non-text prompt to help determine where things should be placed in the generated image. See [this question](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/68/how-can-i-generate-a-subject-in-a-specific-pose/69#69) for more information about how to use these to achieve a certain pose. Below I use a pose T2I adapter to make sure the full figure is within the image bounds:

[image: Pose skeleton input and the generated result of a figure in the same pose as the input pose skeleton]